# Visual Studio 2019 cannot find binding info but VS 2015 is fine

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfvc, visual-studio-2019, source-control-bindings

When I open a project in VS 2019 (or 2017) I get the message:

> The solution you are opening is bound to source control on the following...Would you like to contact this server to try to enable source control integration.

I click Yes and receive:

> The solution appears to be under source control, but its binding information cannot be found...

VS 2015 opens projects just fine. What is the deal?

Comment: I have connected before and I don't really want to try again considering I have submitted an issue of connecting taking hours : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/527915/connect-to-a-project-with-tfs-server-takes-an-hour.html

Comment: I pinged the maintainer of Team Explorer.

Comment: You could try to run `tf vc status $/ /collection:https://yourtfsserver` from a Visual Studio 2019 command prompt to trigger the connection directly.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: This is working. However, we have a collection per client and I find I need to run this command for each client's collection before I open a project in that collection. So, it works but it is situationally inconvenient - which is not your fault. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the connection and workspace cache of your Team Explorer 2019 is populated, it needs to connect to the server at least once before it will know how to bind the solution to source control.

You can do this through the Connect to... option in Team Explorer.

If, as you described, that dialog is giving you lemons, the alternative is to connect the workspace through the commandline. Open a `Developer Command  for VS 201x` (matching the version of Visual Studio you're trying to connect from) and from there issue the following command to force a connection:

```
tf vc status $/ /collection:https://yourtfsserver
```

[image]

After this one-time command that workspace should work again. if you have a lot of workspaces on your machine, or a lot of Project Collections on your TFS server, creating a little batch script may be useful ;).

Comment: I'm now getting mixed results. This is only working about 30% of the time for me.

Comment: I suspect it only works well for collections that have an existing workspace for this workstation.

Comment: How do I properly add a workspace each time I am needing to work on a project again in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Because when I go to add a new workspace I am already locked into the last collection I happen to have connected with. It appears I cannot change to a different client's collection at this point.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/VC6chub24oD If I go to add a workspace I cannot change the collection from what is already specified.

Comment: It is what you pass in from the commandline. Use the `/collection:` argument.